# Is it possible to use Google Lens from the desktop version of Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I frequently use the Google Photos application on my Android phone, where I make use of the Google Lens feature there. Right now I'm managing my photos from [the Google Photos web application](https://photos.google.com) in Firefox and I notice the Google Lens feature seems to be missing completely. I checked [the Google Lens page](https://lens.google.com/) and although this question is not addressed explicitly, it looks as if Google Lens might only available be Android and iOS? Is that really true? It makes no sense to me at all. Am I missing something or is this feature really just not available from a desktop OS like Windows 10?

Comment: I'm just commenting to get notified whenever this changes or gets solved ^_^

Comment: I've recently found that, although not exactly like Google Lens, putting an image in to Google Image search on desktop can yield similar information.

Comment: I believe now you can use the 'Copy text from image' feature on photos.google.com .

Comment: @TeddyC I don't see the option... care to submit and answer with a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is the reply to Brian's comment:)

'Copy text from image' feature on photos.google.com:

[image]

(Chrome PWA on macOS, with photo redacted)